Unauthorized 401 Error While Using Mistral Chat Completions API
I keep getting a 401: Unauthorized error while trying to use the Mistral API to generate some text for me. I'm 101% sure my api key is not the problem.
Here is the error message:
 Response: {
  "message":"Unauthorized",
  "request_id":"5382d0543a83b32ddea2e47d5988c20a"
}

Here is the section of the code relating to the set up:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const runtime = 'nodejs';
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

const INITIAL_SUGGESTIONS = 8;
const SIMILAR_SUGGESTIONS = 7;
const SINGLE_SUGGESTION = 1;

const MAX_RETRIES = 3;
const RETRY_DELAY = 1000; // 1 second
const FETCH_TIMEOUT = 10000; // 10 seconds timeout

const MISTRAL_API_URL = 'https://api.mistral.ai/v1/chat/completion';

async function fetchWithTimeout(url: string, options: RequestInit, timeout = FETCH_TIMEOUT): Promise<Response> {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const id = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), timeout);

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        ...options,
        signal: controller.signal
      });
      clearTimeout(id);
      resolve(response);
    } catch (error) {
      clearTimeout(id);
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}

async function retryFetch(url: string, options: RequestInit, retries = MAX_RETRIES): Promise<Response> {
  try {
    return await fetchWithTimeout(url, options);
  } catch (error) {
    if (retries > 0) {
      console.log(`Fetch failed, retrying... ${retries} attempts remaining`);
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, RETRY_DELAY));
      return retryFetch(url, options, retries - 1);
    }
    throw error;
  }
}



I reseached online and found others with the issue, they claimed it was the endpoint, and I changed it from https://api.mistral.ai/v1/chat/completion to https://codestral.mistral.ai/v1/chat/completions. But that didn't work, so i changed back to the former.

I don't see where you are sending an api key at all.  Or is that implied by ...options, ?
